# Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'serverError'

Tags: mysql, error-handling, google-cloud-messaging, sails.js, waterline

I am using node.js: sailsjs on ubuntu

```
node version: 0.10.37
sails version: 0.11.0
npm version: 1.4.28
ubuntu version: 14.04.2
```

I am trying to log the value returned by GCM push notification service into a mysql table. The part of push notification service (`PushNotifications.js` file) with which I am logging into the db table, is shown below:

```
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('Response from GCM: ' + chunk);
                    GcmLog.add(recipients, chunk, function(err, response){
                        if(err){
                            res.serverError(err);
                        }else{
                            res.json({msg: 'yes'});
                        }
                    });
    });
});
```

The `GcmLog.js` model has the following function to push the data into the db table:

```
  add: function(device_id, chunk, callback){
        GcmLog.create({user: device_id, log: chunk}).exec(function(err, response){
            if(err){
                return callback(err, null);
            }else{
        callback(null, response);
      }
    });
  }
```

When I send a push notification, the message is delivered successfully and displayed on the android device, but nothing gets logged into the db table. I am getting the following error in the log file of the app:

```
/path/to/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:82
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'serverError'
    at /path/to/api/services/PushNotifications.js:44:13
    at /path/to/api/models/GcmLog.js:29:12
    at bound (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:416:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:326:16)
    at _normalizeCallback.callback.error (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:42:31)
    at _switch (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:46:28)
    at /path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:216:14
    at bound (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:416:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:326:16)
    at _normalizeCallback.callback.error (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:42:31)
    at _switch (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:46:28)
    at afterwards (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/dql.js:88:16)
    at bound (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:957:21)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/path/to/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:416:80)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

And then the server crashes and restarts after several attempts. I am unable to trace out the reason for this. Any help in explanation of what is happening and how to overcome this, will be appreciated.